# Captcha vs Hidden Field

Tags: html, security, captcha

I'm been recently wondering if the complexity of a decent captcha was acceptable for a simple website. I wonder if only using an `input` field with a `hidden` attribute in CSS would be sufficient for a simple protection in HTML ?

Comment: Because hackers can scan the source of the document and can easily pass the captcha verification

Comment: Can't you hide it with Javascript ?

Comment: JS is client side, you need to obfuscate it using server side language but again if you use `base64` it can be decoded, and if you use md5 or sha1 than they cannot be, as they are one way encoding, instead simply use captcha :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hidden CSS attribute will not suffice. The contents of the input field will still be readable from the page source. Any bot or external program which will read your page source can read the value, regardless of the visibility in the CSS.

A good Captcha will always require user input, because if no user input is required for a Captcha it can always be "cracked" by an algorithm.

Comment: If I put a `visibility: none` on the field, will it appear on the page ?

Comment: @Xaltar Of course it appears in the DOM/Source document, it just hides it from the front end